# How to Custom Datagridview Sort Like this

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, winforms

I have a windows Datagridview with Column values

```
id
---
0
0
0
5
2
7
```

I want ascending sort of this but zero containg cells will be under.
Like this-

```
2
5
7
0
0
0
```

Comment: What is the datasource of the dgv?

Comment: there no dataSource . added the row manually . grid1.rows.add(row);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using data source for your grid, then you can use [DataGridView.SortCompare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare(v=vs.110).aspx) event like this

```
void yourDataGridView_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Name == "Id" && e.CellValue1 != null && e.CellValue2 != null)
    {
        var x = (int)e.CellValue1;
        var y = (int)e.CellValue2;
        e.SortResult = x == y ? 0 : x == 0 ? 1 : y == 0 ? -1 : x.CompareTo(y);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to attach the event handler to your grid view.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned the datasource of your `DataGridView` i show an approach with a collection. For example with an `int[]` but it works with all:

```
int[] collection = { 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 7 };
int[] ordered = collection.OrderBy(i => i == 0).ThenBy(i => i).ToArray();
```

This works because the first `OrderBy` uses a comparison which can either be `true` or `false`. Since `true` is "higher" than `false` all which are not 0 come first. The `ThenBy` is for the *internal* ordering of the non-zero group.

If that's too abstract, maybe you find this more readable:

```
int[] ordered = collection.OrderBy(i => i != 0 ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(i => i).ToArray();
```